# Octave subplots with plotyy, right Y-axis stacking

Tags: matlab, plot, graph, octave

I am having an issue with Octave plotting, where the right axis in the second plot of a subplot using plotyy has overlapping tick marks.

Plot example

[image]

here is a snip of the code, let me know if you need more of my code to solve my issue:

```html
figure(4)
subplot(2,1,1)
[hAy,hLine1,hLine2] = plotyy(t_i,y_Gc(:,1),t_i,y_pos);
ylabel(hAy(1),'Cube Angular Velocity (rad/s)') % left y-axis
ylabel(hAy(2),'Cube Angular Position (rad)') % right y-axis
title('Cube Response')
xlabel('Time (sec)')
subplot(2,1,2)
[hAx,hLine3,hLine4] = plotyy(t_i(1:end-1),y_vel(1:end-1),t_i(1:end-1),y_torque);
ylabel(hAx(1),'Motor-A Angular Velocity (rad/s)') % left y-axis
ylabel(hAx(2),'Motor Torque (mNm)') % right y-axis
title('Motor A Response')
xlabel('Time (sec)')
```

I don't think it makes a difference but I am using gnuplot by adding: graphics_toolkit("gnuplot")

Comment: Which version of Octave do you use? I tried it using dummy data in v4.0.2 (on Win10, if that should matter). with both ``graphics_toolkit("gnuplot")`` and ``graphics_toolkit("gltk")`` without getting any overlapping ticks.

Comment: I am using the version that installs on Ubuntu 15.10 using apt-get, I will double check the version when I get home.
I double checked to see if it was gnuplot by changing back to default plotting and nothing changed. Also if it makes any difference I am doing controls design so the data that is being plotted is the result of lsim commands from MIMO systems (y_Gc is technically the only MIMO system and as you can see in the plot on line 3 of my posted snip I am only calling the first output)

Comment: I am using Octave v4.0.0

Comment: Tried now with Octave v4.0.0 on Ubuntu 15.10, and I still don't get any overlapping ticks when I use random dummy data. If your data is generated in Octave, any chance you can edit your question to include that part of the code I so can try with the same data? (Or if you can upload the data to someplace).